# Dial phone in background in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I am developing a project where i want to implement dial functionality from within app.

The problem is it takes the control to Phone app of iPhone and my app goes in background. I want the Phone app in background rather my app.

So how can we send the dialing app in background and my app being steady and viewable.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible on iOS. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for reply, is there any alternative to do it in iPhone app?

Comment: Have a look at the Favorites App by Matt Gemmell he probably implemented the best available solution. While this will not give you insights into his code, it might give you an idea of an achievable user experience.

Answer (score 0):

However this is not possible in iOS. You can try this.

Create and Local Notification when call app starts. Then a notification will be fired and user will be prompted to get the app to the foreground, and done so. The phone app goes to backgroud.

Comment: Thanks, query is do i have to write key for foreground in info.plist or do some local push notification.

Comment: But problem is when user dials from app it takes it to phone app and then local notification happens. But isnt it possible to keep my app in foreground.